# Improve efficiency for a map command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, inventory, foreach

I have 4 databases in my rails program, Products, Offerings, OfferingProducts, and Orders

Sample Offering: Medium Kit

Medium Kit Contains 2 Products (This is set up in the OfferingProduct db)
1 Small
2 Medium

customer Orders 2 medium kits

this program should account for 2 Small and 4 Medium from this order and many orders similar

I'm trying to set up an inventory system to track how many of each product are sold every week so that I can reorder products. To calculate this I have:

```
def get_trend
  product = Product.first
  customer_orders =[]
  product.offerings.each do |o|
    customer_orders = customer_orders + o.orders
  end
  o=customer_orders.group_by { |t| t.date.beginning_of_week }
  y = []
  op=self.offering_products;
  o.sort.each do |week, orders|
    y << orders.map { |o| o.quantity*op.find_by_offering_id(o.offering).quantity }.sum
  end
  return y
end
```

This seems to work, but it takes about 20 seconds to calculate. Is there any way to make this faster? I know most of the time is taken by the

```
y << orders.map { |o| o.quantity*op.find_by_offering_id(o.offering).quantity }.sum
```

line which calculates the number of products ordered in a given week. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you really using separate databases or just separate tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing thanks to the info from Iain

```
def get_trend
    sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
    if Rails.env == "production"
        d=sql.execute("SELECT SUM(orders.quantity * offering_products.quantity), EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM orders.date) AS year, EXTRACT(WEEK FROM orders.date) AS week " +
        " FROM orders " +
        " INNER JOIN offerings ON offerings.id = orders.offering_id " + 
        " INNER JOIN offering_products ON offering_products.offering_id = offerings.id " +
        " INNER JOIN products ON products.id = offering_products.product_id " +
        " WHERE (products.id = #{self.id}) GROUP BY year, week ORDER BY year, week ")
        y=d.map { |a| a["sum"].to_i }
    else
        d=sql.execute("SELECT SUM(orders.quantity * offering_products.quantity), strftime('%G-%V', orders.date) AS year " +
        " FROM orders " +
        " INNER JOIN offerings ON offerings.id = orders.offering_id " +
        " INNER JOIN offering_products ON offering_products.offering_id = offerings.id " + 
        " INNER JOIN products ON products.id = offering_products.product_id " +
        " WHERE (products.id = #{self.id}) GROUP BY year")
        y=d.map { |a| a[0] }
    end
    return y
end
```

Update: needed to differentiate the code between production and local, because heroku uses postgresql, and the date functions work differently:( which also means the result isnt exactly the same, because the functions treat the first week of the year differently.

Comment: That looks a lot better. I don't use ActiveRecord often (I much prefer Sequel) but I'm sure there will be a way that you can get joins via the AR code without using SQL. This article might be worth a read at some point: http://www.sofer.com/blog/using-joins-in-active-record.html

Comment: So the problem with this is that it only works locally, the sql doesnt execute on heroku because it uses postgresql... gonna have to try again and let you know

Comment: A heredoc might be easier to read than all that string concatenation. Also, `Rails.env.production?` is shorthand for `Rails.env == 'production'`. Also, make sure you aren't interpolating any variables that a user can input (to avoid SQL injection).

Comment: It's very easy nowadays to get Postgres set up on your development machine, the binaries are on this page: http://www.postgresql.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using iterations (i.e loops in application code) when you'd be better off using declarations (i.e. joins in the database). Loops will never be as fast as joins, and moving the dataset into the application's memory won't be helping either.

I'm guessing you're using ActiveRecord? If so, this may help with how to query with joins: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html